# How to find out if an instance in aws ec2 dashboard is an app server or db server?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server, cloud

How to find out if an instance showing under AWS Ec2 Dashboard is an app server or db server?

I am new to AWS, so any help is much appreciated.

It is just a question. We have been given one instance name which we can see in the Ec2 Dashboard and we have been asked if it is an app server or db server and share the details.

Comment: Are you asking if your EC2 instance is running an App server or a database?

Comment: Unless your team has labeling or proper tags the dashboard alone won't tell you anything.  Amazon doesn't guess what you have deployed on your servers.

Comment: Look at the instance tags, look at the security groups (you can probably infer app vs db server from open inbound port numbers), or look at the automation that deployed the system (e.g. CloudFormation template).

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I am asking if the EC2 instance is running an App server or a database. Nothing in the dashboard indicates that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing in the EC2 dashboard because every EC2 instance is just a virtual machine, the Amazon interface does not care what is actually running on your virtual machine.

However, within the AWS Console there is a seperate service called Amazon RDS which is a fully managed database service where you can make dedicated relational-based databases.

---

If you would like to find out if your EC2 is an "app" or "db" server the only way to do that at this point would be to SSH into the server and check what is running on the machine.